# Is it possible to set a filter to a background image here?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I need to apply filters to my background image and ideally I want to do it where its being added and without changing much existing code. Is it possible to that inside this function?

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage(image_library_selected_url, function() {
    canvas.renderAll();
    _canvasBrowser_update();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really but this works

```
if(requiresFilters) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(image_library_selected_url, (function(image){
      image.filters.push(grayscale);
      image.filters.push(tint);
      image.applyFilters((function(){
        this.canvas.backgroundImage = image.getElement();
        this.canvas.renderAll();
      }).bind(this));
    }).bind(this));
} else {
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(image_library_selected_url, function() {
        canvas.renderAll();
        _canvasBrowser_update();
    });                     
}
```